# A (square) integer matrix which doesn't diagonalize over $\mathbb{Z}$ also doesn't diagonalize over some $\mathbb{Z}/p^{k}$

Tags: linear-algebra, number-theory, diagonalization

Motivated by a series of [recent Twitter polls](https://twitter.com/littmath/status/1753238520410357899) by Daniel Litt, we ask (and answer, since the issue doesn't seem to have previously been addressed on this site) the following natural question:

Given a natural $\text{d}$, a $\text{d}\times\text{d}$ matrix $A$ with integer entries, and a commutative ring $\mathbb{E}$, say that $A$ diagonalizes over $\mathbb{E}$ if there exists a matrix $F\in\text{GL}_{\text{d}}\left(\mathbb{E}\right)$ with $F^{-1}AF$ diagonal (over $\mathbb{E}$). Clearly if $A$ diagonalizes over $\mathbb{Z}$, then it diagonalizes over every $\mathbb{E}$.

**Question:** If $A$ doesn't diagonalize over $\mathbb{Z}$, must there there exist a prime $p$ and natural $k$ such that $A$ also doesn't diagonalize over $\mathbb{Z}/p^{k}$?

Answer (score 1):

$\require{AMScd}$Think of $A$ as a $\mathbb{Z}$-linear map $\mathbb{Z}^{\text{d}}\overset{A}{\to}\mathbb{Z}^{\text{d}}$ as per the standard basis of $\mathbb{Z}^{\text{d}}$. As we will be interested in taking the kernels of $A$ and of related maps, we will henceforth very explicitly denote the$\pmod{p^{k}}$ reduction of $A$ as $\mathbb{Z}/p^{k}\otimes_{\mathbb{Z}}A$ wherever we consider it. Otherwise, where $A$ appears in isolation, it can and should be assumed to be over $\mathbb{Z}$.

---

In general, given a $\text{d}\times\text{d}$ matrix $A$, there are three possible cases:

**Case I:** *$A$'s characteristic polynomial doesn't split into (not necessarily distinct) linear factors over $\mathbb{Z}$.*

By Gauss's lemma, $A$'s characteristic polynomial then doesn't split into linear factors over $\mathbb{Q}$. By Chebotarev's density theorem(!!), there then exists a prime $p$ such that $\mathbb{Z}/p\otimes_{\mathbb{Z}}A$'s characteristic polynomial (which is inherited from $\mathbb{Z}$) also doesn't split into linear factors over $\mathbb{Z}/p$. In particular, $\mathbb{Z}/p\otimes_{\mathbb{Z}}A$ must not diagonalize over $\mathbb{Z}/p$.

(Implicitly using that $A$'s characteristic polynomial is a similarity-invariant thereof and the characteristic polynomial of a diagonal matrix manifestly splits into linear factors.)

**Case II:** *$A$'s characteristic polynomial does split into (not necessarily distinct) linear factors over $\mathbb{Z}$, with (distinct) roots $\lambda_{0},\dots,\lambda_{\text{n}-1}$ of respective multiplicities $e_{0},\dots,e_{\text{n}-1}>0$, but $$\text{coker}\left(\bigoplus_{\text{j}\colon\text{n}}\text{ker}\left(\lambda_{\text{j}}-A\right)\ \overset{\left(\text{inc.}_{\text{j}}\right)_{\text{j}\colon\text{n}}}{\to}\ \mathbb{Z}^{\text{d}}\right)\ \not\simeq\ 0$$ (where $\lambda_{\text{j}}-A$ is shorthand for $\lambda_{\text{j}}$ times the $\text{d}\times\text{d}$ identity matrix minus $A$ and the components $\text{ker}\left(\lambda_{\text{j}}-A\right)\overset{\text{inc.}_{\text{j}}}{\to}\mathbb{Z}^{\text{d}}$ are the canonical kernel inclusions).*

By the classification of finitely generated $\mathbb{Z}$-modules, there exists $p$ such that $$\mathbb{Z}/p\otimes_{\mathbb{Z}}\text{coker}\left(\bigoplus_{\text{j}\colon\text{n}}\text{ker}\left(\lambda_{\text{j}}-A\right)\ \overset{\left(\text{inc.}\right)_{\text{j}\colon\text{n}}}{\to}\ \mathbb{Z}^{\text{d}}\right)\ \not\simeq\ 0\text{;}$$ given such $p$ denote by $L$ the largest natural such that $p^{L}$ divides a nonzero diagonal entry of the $\mathbb{Z}$-Smith normal form of some $\lambda_{\text{j}}-A$. We claim that $\mathbb{Z}/p^{\text{d}L+1}\otimes_{\mathbb{Z}}A$ does not diagonalize over $\mathbb{Z}/p^{\text{d}L+1}$.

Indeed, consider the commutative diagram
\begin{CD}\bigoplus_{\text{j}\colon\text{n}}\mathbb{Z}/p\otimes_{\mathbb{Z}}\text{ker}\left(\lambda_{\text{j}}-A\right) @>\left(\mathbb{Z}/p\otimes_{\mathbb{Z}}\text{inc.}_{\text{j}}\right)_{\text{j}\colon\text{n}}>> \mathbb{Z}/p\otimes_{\mathbb{Z}}\mathbb{Z}^{\text{d}} @>\mathbb{Z}/p\otimes_{\mathbb{Z}}\text{pro.}>> \mathbb{Z}/p\otimes_{\mathbb{Z}}\text{coker}\left(\bigoplus_{\text{j}\colon\text{n}}\text{ker}\left(\lambda_{\text{j}}-A\right)\ \overset{\left(\text{inc.}_{\text{j}}\right)_{\text{j}\colon\text{n}}}{\to}\ \mathbb{Z}^{\text{d}}\right)\\ @V\bigoplus_{\text{j}\colon\text{n}}\mathbb{Z}/p\otimes_{\mathbb{Z}}\text{can.}^{L+1}_{\text{j}}VV @V\mathbb{Z}/p\otimes_{\mathbb{Z}}\text{red.}V\simeq V @V\exists !VV\\ \bigoplus_{\text{j}\colon\text{n}}\mathbb{Z}/p\otimes_{\mathbb{Z}}\text{ker}\left(\mathbb{Z}/p^{L+1}\otimes_{\mathbb{Z}}\left(\lambda_{\text{j}}-A\right)\right) @>\left(\mathbb{Z}/p\otimes_{\mathbb{Z}}\text{inc.}^{L+1}_{\text{j}}\right)_{\text{j}\colon\text{n}}>> \mathbb{Z}/p\otimes_{\mathbb{Z}}\mathbb{Z}/p^{L+1}\otimes_{\mathbb{Z}}\mathbb{Z}^{\text{d}} @>\mathbb{Z}/p\otimes_{\mathbb{Z}}\text{pro.}^{L+1}>> \mathbb{Z}/p\otimes_{\mathbb{Z}}\text{coker}\left(\bigoplus_{\text{j}\colon\text{n}}\text{ker}\left(\mathbb{Z}/p^{L+1}\otimes_{\mathbb{Z}}\left(\lambda_{\text{j}}-A\right)\right)\ \overset{\left(\text{inc.}^{L+1}_{\text{j}}\right)_{\text{j}\colon\text{n}}}{\to}\ \mathbb{Z}/p^{L+1}\otimes_{\mathbb{Z}}\mathbb{Z}^{\text{d}}\right)
\end{CD}
where:

- The components $$\text{ker}\left(\mathbb{Z}/p^{L+1}\otimes_{\mathbb{Z}}\left(\lambda_{\text{j}}-A\right)\right)\ \overset{\text{inc.}^{L+1}_{\text{j}}}{\to}\ \mathbb{Z}/p^{L+1}\otimes_{\mathbb{Z}}\mathbb{Z}^{\text{d}}$$ are the analogous canonical kernel inclusions (not in general the same as $\mathbb{Z}/p^{L+1}\otimes_{\mathbb{Z}}\text{inc.}_{\text{j}}$!).
- The maps $$\mathbb{Z}^{\text{d}}\ \overset{\text{pro}.}{\to}\ \text{coker}\left(\bigoplus_{\text{j}\colon\text{n}}\text{ker}\left(\lambda_{\text{j}}-A\right)\ \overset{\left(\text{inc.}_{\text{j}}\right)_{\text{j}\colon\text{n}}}{\to}\ \mathbb{Z}^{\text{d}}\right)$$ $$\mathbb{Z}/p^{L+1}\otimes_{\mathbb{Z}}\mathbb{Z}^{\text{d}}\ \overset{\text{pro.}^{L+1}}{\to}\ \text{coker}\left(\bigoplus_{\text{j}\colon\text{n}}\text{ker}\left(\mathbb{Z}/p^{L+1}\otimes_{\mathbb{Z}}\left(\lambda_{\text{j}}-A\right)\right)\ \overset{\left(\text{inc.}^{L+1}_{\text{j}}\right)_{\text{j}\colon\text{n}}}{\to}\ \mathbb{Z}/p^{L+1}\otimes_{\mathbb{Z}}\mathbb{Z}^{\text{d}}\right)$$ are the canonical cokernel morphisms (so that the rows of the diagram are themselves cokernel projections, by that $\mathbb{Z}/p\otimes_{\mathbb{Z}}-$ canonically preserves $\bigoplus_{\text{j}\colon\text{n}}$ and cokernels).
- The biproductands $$\text{ker}\left(\lambda_{\text{j}}-A\right)\ \overset{\text{can.}^{L+1}_{\text{j}}}{\to}\ \text{ker}\left(\mathbb{Z}/p^{L+1}\otimes_{\mathbb{Z}}\left(\lambda_{\text{j}}-A\right)\right)$$ are the canonical kernel-to-kernel-of-tensor-product maps.
- The map $$\mathbb{Z}^{\text{d}}\ \overset{\text{red.}}{\to}\ \mathbb{Z}/p^{L+1}\otimes_{\mathbb{Z}}\mathbb{Z}^{\text{d}}$$ is the canonical$\pmod{p^{L+1}}$ reduction map (which becomes an isomorphism upon the application of $\mathbb{Z}/p\otimes_{\mathbb{Z}}$).

By the construction of $L$, every element of $\text{ker}\left(\mathbb{Z}/p^{L+1}\otimes_{\mathbb{Z}}\left(\lambda_{\text{j}}-A\right)\right)\subseteq\mathbb{Z}/p^{L+1}\otimes_{\mathbb{Z}}\mathbb{Z}^{\text{d}}$ is equivalent$\pmod{p}$ to the$\pmod{p^{L+1}}$-reduction of an element of $\text{ker}\left(\lambda_{\text{j}}-A\right)\subseteq\mathbb{Z}^{\text{d}}$. It follows that the images of the maps $$\bigoplus_{\text{j}\colon\text{n}}\mathbb{Z}/p\otimes_{\mathbb{Z}}\text{ker}\left(\lambda_{\text{j}}-A\right)\ \overset{\left(\mathbb{Z}/p\otimes_{\mathbb{Z}}\text{inc.}_{\text{j}}\right)_{\text{j}\colon\text{n}}}{\to}\ \mathbb{Z}/p\otimes_{\mathbb{Z}}\mathbb{Z}^{\text{d}}$$ $$\bigoplus_{\text{j}\colon\text{n}}\mathbb{Z}/p\otimes_{\mathbb{Z}}\text{ker}\left(\mathbb{Z}/p^{L+1}\otimes_{\mathbb{Z}}\left(\lambda_{\text{j}}-A\right)\right)\ \overset{\left(\mathbb{Z}/p\otimes_{\mathbb{Z}}\text{inc.}^{L+1}_{\text{j}}\right)_{\text{j}\colon\text{n}}}{\to}\ \mathbb{Z}/p\otimes_{\mathbb{Z}}\mathbb{Z}/p^{L+1}\otimes_{\mathbb{Z}}\mathbb{Z}^{\text{d}}$$ are identified by the isomorphism $\mathbb{Z}/p\otimes\text{red.}$. In particular, the map $$\mathbb{Z}/p\otimes_{\mathbb{Z}}\text{coker}\left(\bigoplus_{\text{j}\colon\text{n}}\text{ker}\left(\lambda_{\text{j}}-A\right)\ \overset{\left(\text{inc.}_{\text{j}}\right)_{\text{j}\colon\text{n}}}{\to}\ \mathbb{Z}^{\text{d}}\right)\ \overset{\exists!}{\to}\ \mathbb{Z}/p\otimes_{\mathbb{Z}}\text{coker}\left(\bigoplus_{\text{j}\colon\text{n}}\text{ker}\left(\mathbb{Z}/p^{L+1}\otimes_{\mathbb{Z}}\left(\lambda_{\text{j}}-A\right)\right)\ \overset{\left(\text{inc.}^{L+1}_{\text{j}}\right)_{\text{j}\colon\text{n}}}{\to}\ \mathbb{Z}/p^{L+1}\otimes_{\mathbb{Z}}\mathbb{Z}^{\text{d}}\right)$$ from the above diagram is itself an isomorphism, so that by assumption $$\mathbb{Z}/p\otimes_{\mathbb{Z}}\text{coker}\left(\bigoplus_{\text{j}\colon\text{n}}\text{ker}\left(\mathbb{Z}/p^{L+1}\otimes_{\mathbb{Z}}\left(\lambda_{\text{j}}-A\right)\right)\ \overset{\left(\text{inc.}^{L+1}_{\text{j}}\right)_{\text{j}\colon\text{n}}}{\to}\ \mathbb{Z}/p^{L+1}\otimes_{\mathbb{Z}}\mathbb{Z}^{\text{d}}\right)\ \not\simeq\ 0\text{.}$$

Now suppose (for the sake of contradiction to this last non-isomorphism) that $\mathbb{Z}/p^{\text{d}L+1}\otimes_{\mathbb{Z}}A$ did diagonalize over $\mathbb{Z}/p^{\text{d}L+1}$, specifically with (not necessarily distinct) diagonal entries $\left(\beta_{\text{i}}\in\mathbb{Z}/p^{\text{d}L+1}\right)_{\text{i}\colon\text{d}}$. Manifestly, $$\text{coker}\left(\bigoplus_{\text{i}\colon\text{d}}\text{ker}\left(\beta_{\text{i}}-\mathbb{Z}/p^{L+1}\otimes_{\mathbb{Z}}A\right)\ \overset{\left(\text{inc.}'_{\text{i}}\right)_{\text{i}\colon\text{d}}}{\to}\ \mathbb{Z}/p^{L+1}\otimes_{\mathbb{Z}}\mathbb{Z}^{\text{d}}\right)\ \simeq\ 0\text{,}$$ (where the components $$\text{ker}\left(\beta_{\text{i}}-\mathbb{Z}/p^{L+1}\otimes_{\mathbb{Z}}A\right)\ \overset{\text{inc.}'_{\text{i}}}{\to}\ \mathbb{Z}/p^{L+1}\otimes_{\mathbb{Z}}\mathbb{Z}^{\text{d}}$$ are yet again the relevant canonical kernel inclusions). Each $\beta_{\text{i}}$ must (by the same argument as in **Case I**) be a root of $\mathbb{Z}/p^{\text{d}L+1}\otimes_{\mathbb{Z}}A$'s characteristic polynomial in $\mathbb{Z}/p^{\text{d}L+1}$, so must agree with some $\lambda_{\text{j}}$$\pmod{p^{L+1}}$. Thus there is a surjection $$0\ \simeq\ \text{coker}\left(\bigoplus_{\text{i}\colon\text{d}}\text{ker}\left(\beta_{\text{i}}-\mathbb{Z}/p^{L+1}\otimes_{\mathbb{Z}}A\right)\ \overset{\left(\text{inc.}'_{\text{i}}\right)_{\text{i}\colon\text{d}}}{\to}\ \mathbb{Z}/p^{L+1}\otimes_{\mathbb{Z}}\mathbb{Z}^{\text{d}}\right)\ \twoheadrightarrow\ \text{coker}\left(\bigoplus_{\text{j}\colon\text{n}}\text{ker}\left(\mathbb{Z}/p^{L+1}\otimes_{\mathbb{Z}}\left(\lambda_{\text{j}}-A\right)\right)\ \overset{\left(\text{inc.}^{L+1}_{\text{j}}\right)_{\text{j}\colon\text{n}}}{\to}\ \mathbb{Z}/p^{L+1}\otimes_{\mathbb{Z}}\mathbb{Z}^{\text{d}}\right)\text{,}$$ the desired contradiction.

**Case III:** *$A$'s characteristic polynomial does split into (not necessarily distinct) linear factors over $\mathbb{Z}$, with (distinct) roots $\lambda_{0},\dots,\lambda_{\text{n}-1}$ of respective multiplicities $e_{0},\dots,e_{\text{n}-1}>0$, and $$\text{coker}\left(\bigoplus_{\text{j}\colon\text{n}}\text{ker}\left(\lambda_{\text{j}}-A\right)\ \overset{\left(\text{inc.}_{\text{j}}\right)_{\text{j}\colon\text{n}}}{\to}\ \mathbb{Z}^{\text{d}}\right)\ \simeq\ 0$$ (with the same notation as in **Case II**).*

Observe that $\left(\text{inc.}_{\text{j}}\right)_{\text{j}\colon\text{n}}$ is in any case injective, since for any $\left(v_{\text{j}}\right)_{\text{j}\colon\text{n}}\in\text{coker}\left(\bigoplus_{\text{j}\colon\text{n}}\text{ker}\left(\lambda_{\text{j}}-A\right)\right)$, $$\left(\lambda_{\text{n}-1}-A\right)\cdots\left(\lambda_{\text{j}'+1}-A\right)\left(\lambda_{\text{j}'-1}-A\right)\cdots\left(\lambda_{0}-A\right)\text{inc.}\left(\left(v_{\text{j}}\right)_{\text{j}\colon\text{n}}\right)\ =\ \underbrace{\left(\lambda_{\text{n}-1}-\lambda_{\text{j}'}\right)\cdots\left(\lambda_{\text{j}'+1}-\lambda_{\text{j}'}\right)\left(\lambda_{\text{j}'-1}-\lambda_{\text{j}'}\right)\cdots\left(\lambda_{0}-\lambda_{\text{j}'}\right)}_{>\ 0}\text{inc.}_{\text{j}'}\left(v_{\text{j}'}\right)$$ for all $\text{j}'\colon\text{n}$. I.e., $\left(\text{inc.}_{\text{j}}\right)_{\text{j}\colon\text{n}}$ is in this case an isomorphism. As each $\text{ker}\left(\lambda_{\text{j}}-A\right)$ is a free $\mathbb{Z}$-module (being a sub-$\mathbb{Z}$-module of $\mathbb{Z}^{\text{d}}$), a $\mathbb{Z}$-basis of $\mathbb{Z}^{\text{d}}$ in which $\mathbb{A}$ diagonalizes can be constructed by choosing a  $\mathbb{Z}$-basis for each of its biproductands and taking their collective image under $\left(\text{inc.}_{\text{j}}\right)_{\text{j}\colon\text{n}}$.

---

TL;DR: in **Case I** and **Case II**, $A$'s failure to diagonalize over $\mathbb{Z}$ is inherited over some $\mathbb{Z}/p^{k}$. In **Case III**, $A$ does diagonalize over $\mathbb{Z}$. As the three cases span the space of possibilities (and are mutually exclusive), the claim follows. $\blacksquare$

Answer (score 0):

Here's a much shorter means by which to handle the long step of [the other answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4859438/580423) (i.e., fitting **Case II** into the classification), albeit dependent upon the axiom of countable choice and without the effective bound of the more involved argument. Maintaining its notation,

**Claim:** *If $A$'s characteristic polynomial splits into (not necessarily distinct) linear factors over $\mathbb{Z}$, with (distinct) roots $\lambda_{0},\dots,\lambda_{\text{n}-1}$ of respective multiplicities $e_{0},\dots,e_{\text{n}-1}>0$, and if for all primes $p$ and naturals $k$ the matrix $A$ diagonalizes over each $Z/p^{\text{k}}$, then $$\text{coker}\left(\bigoplus_{\text{j}\colon\text{n}}\text{ker}\left(\lambda_{\text{j}}-A\right)\ \overset{\left(\text{inc.}_{\text{j}}\right)_{\text{j}\colon\text{n}}}{\to}\ \mathbb{Z}^{\text{d}}\right)\ \simeq\ 0\text{.}$$ (The original claim in **Case II** being the contrapositive.)*

**Proof:** If $A$ diagonalizes over each $\mathbb{Z}/p^{\text{k}}$, then by [König's lemma](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/K%C3%B6nig%27s_Tree_Lemma#Theorem) (applied separately to each prime $p$) it diagonalizes over each $\hat{\mathbb{Z}}_{p}$. As each $\hat{\mathbb{Z}}_{p}\otimes_{\mathbb{Z}}-$ is exact, it follows that $$\hat{\mathbb{Z}}_{p}\otimes_{\mathbb{Z}}\text{coker}\left(\bigoplus_{\text{j}\colon\text{n}}\text{ker}\left(\lambda_{\text{j}}-A\right)\ \overset{\left(\text{inc.}_{\text{j}}\right)_{\text{j}\colon\text{n}}}{\to}\ \mathbb{Z}^{\text{d}}\right)\ \simeq\ \text{coker}\left(\bigoplus_{\text{j}\colon\text{n}}\text{ker}\left(\lambda_{\text{j}}-\hat{\mathbb{Z}}_{p}\otimes_{\mathbb{Z}}A\right)\ \overset{\left(\hat{\text{inc.}}_{\text{j}}\right)_{\text{j}\colon\text{n}}}{\to}\ \hat{\mathbb{Z}}_{p}^{\text{d}}\right)\ \simeq\ 0$$ for all primes $p$. The claim is now immediate from the classification of finitely generated $\mathbb{Z}$-modules. (Note that we have implicitly used that the roots of $A$'s characteristic polynomial over each $\hat{\mathbb{Z}}_{p}$ agrees with the roots of the same over $\mathbb{Z}$.) $\Box$